# Word reversion of a string

Tags: java, string

I want to reverse words in a String. I tried to implement it like that:

```
public String reverseWords(String str) {
    String reverse = "";
    String[] arr = str.split(" ");
    for (int i = arr.length; i < 0; i++) {
        reverse+=arr[i];
    }       
    return reverse;
}
```

However, this does not give me anything back? Any recommendations what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are starting from the biggest index, you expect it to be negative(and it never is), not to mention that you are incrementing the index. Do I have to add more to figure it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make loop iterate backward. using `--` and you don't need to go from `0 to length` but from `length` to `1`. It's main logic of manual reverse function.

try this :

```
public static String reverseWords(String str) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length() + 1);
    String[] words = str.split(" ");
    for (int i = words.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sb.append(words[i]).append(' ');
    }
    sb.setLength(sb.length() - 1);  // Strip trailing space
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

try `i=0` to `arr.length` or `i--` and `i>=0`.

Or more elaborate :

You want

```
for (int i=arr.length-1 ; i>=0 ;i--)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have:
`for (int i = arr.length; i < 0; i++) {`

I will always be bigger or equal to 0 if it is length.
Try this:
`for (int i = arr.length; i > 0; i--) {`

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use loop.

version 1:

```
public String reverseWords(String str) {
    String reverse = "";
    for (int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverse+=str.charAt(i);
    }       
    return reverse;
}
```

version 2:

```
 public String reverseWords(String str) {
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str.length()+1);
        for (int i = str.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            sb.append(str.charAt(i));
        }       
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if the string having huge length, moreover if you are in multithreaded environment, it is recommended to go for StringBuffer instead of StringBuilder.

```
public  String reverseWords(String str) {
          return new StringBuffer(str).reverse().toString();
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I giving another option for reversing the string ie  with using charArray in java.
1.copy all the string to char array using function
2. Simply print the character in reverse order.